# What is the best way to destroy a component instance in angular?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular app and it have a button to switch between two components.
I found an issue when i'm playing with the button a bit and sometimes a component is inheriting some behavior from the other component, so I'm looking for a way to start a fresh and clean instance each time i'm switching.
I tried to do some unsubscribe in the `ngOnDestroy()` but it won't help much!

Comment: Post code snippet to help you

Comment: can you give more details please. How do you switch using button. can you give code examples?

Comment: inheriting some behavior mean , you have some design or css issue between two component.?

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer*: I do not prefer writing code that handles creating and destroying components manually. Rather one should rely on framework's routing, child-parent hierarchy and `*ngIf` to create and destroy components. You should of course deal with your code during creation and destruction using `ngOnInit` and `ngOnDestroy`.

However, I assume you are using `ComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory` for manually initialising and destroying component.

If that is the case, you can use :

```
viewContainerRef.clear();
```

where  `viewContainerRef` is your component placeholder. This ensures that no information from previous component is held within the `viewContainerRef` while loading new instances.